# How do I find people name in particular place on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-search

Is there any way to search a name in particular place ?

**For instance :**

Searching all people who have `alex` in their name and living in `New York` city ?

P.S :

My question is not about my friends. It's about all people.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little buggy but you can try

> People named "alex" who live in New York

[image]

https://www.facebook.com/search/str/alex/users-named/112825018731802/residents/present/intersect

Comment: It has not any results!!

Comment: @HamedKamrava you are prob doing it wrong, see edit